# Como salvar um arquivo em um campo no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, arquivo, email

Gostaria de saber como guardar um arquivo dentro de um campo do SQL Server `com C#`. Lendo em alguns foruns eu percebi que existe diferença entre arquivos de imagem e binários.

O tipo de arquivo que eu quero salvar são e-mails do Outlook.
Estou fazendo um sistema onde os cadastros precisam ter algumas provas, e essas provas seriam os e-mails que eu preciso guardar.

Como faço isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Usando o tipo de coluna [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933995%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

[Aqui tem um tutorial sobre como configurar seu SQL Server para usar `FILESTREAM`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream).

Você pode criar tabelas com colunas de arquivos assim:

```
CREATE TABLE MinhaTabela
(
    [Id] [int] primary key identity, 
    [Arquivo] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
)
GO
```

[Aqui tem um passo a passo de como abrir um arquivo e salvá-lo no banco de dados](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/sql-server-2008-filestream-part-3-of-3-using-the-opensqlfilestream-api-2/).