# Como ler e abrir os arquivos de uma coluna de bytes no SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, arquivo

Minha pergunta é a continuação desta pergunta: [Link da outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42645/como-salvar-um-arquivo-em-um-campo-no-sql-server/42654#42654)

Eu consegui transformar meu arquivo em bytes e inserir dentro de uma tabela no SQL Server, porém agora eu quero de dentro de uma aplicação que eu estou fazendo em C# eu quero abrir este arquivo. Ou seja fazer a engenharia reversa (byte > abrir o arquivo).

O código usado para inserção:

```
Anexo a = new Anexo();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(a.Caminho, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
a.Arquivo = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(a.Arquivo, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
string SQL = @"INSERT INTO ANEXO (NOME, CAMINHO, ARQUIVO) VALUES (@nome, @caminho, @arquivo)";
Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, Con);
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = a.NomeArquivo;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@caminho", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = a.Caminho;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@arquivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = a.Arquivo;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Windows form ou Web?

Comment: C# Windows forms

Comment: Qual formato do arquivo? você sabe? PDF, IMAGEM, .TXT, vai  exibir aonde?

Comment: O formato é .msg são os e-mails do Outlook.
Obrigado pelas respostas Paulo

Comment: Você vai pegar do banco e  salvar no computador, correto?

Comment: Não. Ele já está no banco de dados... ai na minha aplicação eu tenho um gridview... e cada tupla deste grid terá um anexo de um e-mail em uma coluna com botão para abrir este anexo. Ai nesta hora que vem a parte de passar de byte para o arquivo e dps abrir.

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver? Neste código que você postou como resposta (foi excluída) aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43713/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-inserir-qualquer-exten%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-arquivo-em-um-banco-de-dados-sql dá pra saber o que está errado. Se tem interesse, posta qui aquele código que te explicamos como resolver.

Answer (score 2):

1. Obtenha o array de bytes e passe para um `MemoryStream` no construtor;
2. Crie seu `FileStream` com o nome do arquivo desejado. Suponho que você esteja salvando pelo menos a extensão original do arquivo (o nome é opcional, mas se você misturar arquivos diferentes, vale a pena salvar uma coluna com os ".eml", ".txt", etc);
3. Leia os bytes do `MemoryStream` e salve no `FileStream`;
4. Se você for abrir o arquivo, pode chamar o `Process.Start`.

```
// aqui está seu array de bytes
byte[] arquivo;
const int BufferSize = 65536;

// create memory stream
using (var mstrm = new MemoryStream(arquivo))
{
    using (var outStream = File.Create("resultado.eml"))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        int bytesLidos;
        while ((bytesLidos = mstrm.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) != 0)
        {
            outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLidos);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edição**

Use o código a seguir para ler o arquivo no seu array de bytes:

```
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string fileName)
{
    byte[] buff = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, 
                               FileMode.Open, 
                               FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    buff = br.ReadBytes((int) numBytes);
    return buff;
}
```

Ele garante que você consegue ler arquivos grande! Sei que seus arquivos não devem ser muito grandes, mas se tiverem anexos grandes podem dar problema.

Para gravar, se não estiver dando certo, você tambén pode usar o jeito que o @Intruso apontou também:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string caminho, byte[] array)
```

Comment: Olá rodrigo. Obrigado pela sua resposta me ajudou. Porém o arquivo é salvo no diretório mas quando eu abro o mesmo a única coisa que vem dentro dele é isto: "System.Byte[]"

Ele não contém os dados do arquivo original....

Comment: @LucasVasconcelos pode postar o código de como está gravando a coluna?

Comment: Adicionei na postagem!! Não estava conseguindo adicionar aqui com indentação.

Comment: @LucasVasconcelos tente ver se isto te ajuda a avançar.

Answer (score 1):

Se seu array representa um arquivo completo:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
```