# Como faço para inserir qualquer extensão de arquivo em um banco de dados SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, banco-de-dados, winforms

Sempre trabalhei anexando apenas imagens em minhas tabelas em BDD, me lembro que convertia para `MemoryStream` e depois para `Byte` e inseria... Mas estou precisando inserir qualquer tipo de extensão de arquivo em meu banco.

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que você insere imagem você pode inserir qualquer tipo de arquivo. Mostre o que você já tem e quais problemas está enfrentando.

Comment: @Caffé Não testei pois o meu campo na minha tabela de imagens está do tipo "Image" então não funcionaria do mesmo modo... qual tipo de campo no banco teria que ser?

Comment: Você pode usar o tipo `varbinary`.

Comment: Isso não resolve, quero inserir o filestream para o banco e também extrair. @Caffé

Comment: Então complemente sua pergunta, descreva os requisitos, mostre exemplos aproximados de como você quer o código... De outro modo quem estiver interessado em ajudar tem que adivinhar o que você precisa.

Comment: Todos exceto você não me exigiram mais nenhum detalhe e conseguiram me responder... não tenho culpa se sua interpretação está fraca. @Caffé

Comment: Sim, e porque você foi bem claro deixaram várias respostas boas e todos responderam muito bem exatamente o que você precisa, certo?

Comment: @CAffé Mais ou menos não quero ficar discutindo, obrigado pela atenção... vou tentar as soluções que me forneceram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forma segura de fazer o que deseja:

```
public static int databaseFilePut(MemoryStream fileToPut) {
    int varID = 0;
    byte[] file = fileToPut.ToArray();
    const string preparedCommand = @"
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Raporty]
                           ([RaportPlik])
                     VALUES
                           (@File)
                    SELECT [RaportID] FROM [dbo].[Raporty]
        WHERE [RaportID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                ";
    using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
    using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
        sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;

        using (var sqlWriteQuery = sqlWrite.ExecuteReader())
            while (sqlWriteQuery != null && sqlWriteQuery.Read()) {
                varID = sqlWriteQuery["RaportID"] is int ? (int) sqlWriteQuery["RaportID"] : 0;
            }
    }
    return varID;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/InsertFile.cs).

Retirado [dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579467/221800).

Dá para simplificar algumas coisas se não precisa de todos os recursos mas você não mostrou sua necessidade específica.

Só não vai tirar os `using` e deixar o código vulnerável à vazamento de recurso.

Note o uso do tipo `VarBinary` para a coluna do SQL Server.

Comment: VarBinary(MAX), certo? mas não entendi a afirmação "modo seguro"

Comment: Pode ser só varbinary na coluna? Ou além de ser varbinary tem que fazer com que o banco receba filestream?

Comment: Meu desejo é que receba o Filestream, caso eu passe apenas como byte não é possivel extrair esse arquivo do banco né?

Comment: @pedro idealmente sim, senão o arquivo deverá ser bem pequeno. O que você chama de extrair do banco? Eu nunca trabalhei com [`FILESTREAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) então não saberia dizer sobre isto. A sua pergunta não fala sobre isto. Eu acredito que basta especificar isto na coluna e o SQL Server vai deixar o arquivo separado. Aí acho que você tem que testar para ver se resolve o que está precisando. Veja isto também: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Comment: @Bigown Me referi a obter o arquivo e salvar em meu disco (extrair) rsrs, não tem na pergunta por que acabei de descobrir isso... Vou testar sua solução logicamente lendo me parece funcionar! Obrigado.

Comment: Você está abrindo três recursos. Eles precisam ser fechados. Usando o `using` é usado, há a garantia que o recursos será encerrado e não deixa ele "pendurado" na aplicação mesmo que ocorra uma exceção ou outro desvio fora do planejado. Este é um erro comum em programação. Quando ocorre um problema, o programador fica perdido sem saber o que está acontecendo e culpa tudo menos o programa errado dele. Quer saber mais? Tem algumas informações aqui no *site*: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16065/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101. Se ainda não entendeu, abra uma pergunta sobre isto.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, usei a dica do tópico original e funcionou aqui. Vlw mesmo