# É possível gravar áudio no banco SQLServer trabalhando com a linguagem vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, áudio

Tenho uma aplicação feito em VB.NET onde tenho cadastros de clientes.
Agora preciso implementar como se fosse uma certa permissão dos clientes para pessoas terceiras que possam representar esses tais clientes.

E é preciso que seja feito com a autorização por voz.

Agora eu não sei se é possível. Ex: Gravar uma frase e armazenar no banco e depois usar esse áudio gravado para apresentar para a empresa responsável.

Se puderem me ajudar, o meu muito obrigado!

Comment: Poderia postar mais detalhes na descrição do tópico? 
Já pesquisou por "vb.net reconhecimento de voz" ou "vb.net voice recognition" (ambos sem aspas) no Google Search?

Comment: Sim é possível basta uma tabela com campo varbinary e você converter o audio para array de bytes. Inclusive já tem uma pergunta sobre isso aqui so SO:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42645/como-salvar-um-arquivo-em-um-campo-no-sql-server

Comment: @JoséDiz, Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Obrigado pela ajuda também...